# Decorator for getting number of times a function is called - How is it working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, decorator, python-decorators

I have to count the number of times a function is called. So, I have written a decorator named `counter` which takes in the function and increments the `calls` attribute by 1. Here is the code:

```
def counter(method):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls += 1
        return method(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapped.calls = 0
    return wrapped
```

Example:

```
@counter
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

multiply(5, 3)
multiply(5, 3)
n_calls = multiply.calls
print(n_calls)
```

It will give the output as 2. Perfect.

What I am unable to understand is: how is it working? Since `calls` is not a global variable (since it is only accessible inside the decorator), how am I able to get the number of function calls by writing `multiply.calls`?

Comment: Where did you get the code? The place which you got the code should probably explain it well

Answer (score 1):

The number of calls is stored as a function attribute, see: `multiply.__dict__`. The decorator initialises this to zero. The call to multiply is replaced with a call to `wrapped`, which you can see by looking at `multiply.__name__`. Wrapped increments `calls` and returns `method(*args, **kwargs)`, where `method` is `multiply`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand decorators, when you define the wrapped function, you create the wrapped.calls attribute.

And when you define your multiply function, it pass it thought the counter function as the "method" argument and returns an instance of the wrapped function which contains the attribute calls.

So your multiply function is in fact an instance of the wrapped function, so it contains the call attribute.